# Show that for any set of 201 positive integers less than 300, there must be two whose quotient is a power of three (with no remainder)

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I guess we should not consider the zeroth power of 3 because it is equal to one. Any positive integer is a multiple of 1.

Lets define the set S3 of integers that are multiples of 3 strictly less than 300. The size of this set is 99, because 99 * 3 = 297.

Lets consider some subset of size 201. 98 integers are thrown out of the initial set. But we can choose 98 out of S3. So only one element of S3 is left. 
Where am I wrong?

Comment: You’re not wrong. But if the set of $201$ integers contains only one multiple of $3$, say $3n$, then it also contains $n$, so it contains two numbers whose quotient is $3$.

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, because I don't understand your argument, but $\{1,2\}\cup \{n : 100 \le n \le 299\}$ is an example of a set of 201 elements of which no two have a quotient of $3$, so you really do need the "power of 3" condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Every integer in the set $\{1,2,\ldots,299\}$ can be written uniquely in the form $3^mn$, where $m\ge 0$, $n\ge 1$, and $n$ is not a multiple of $3$. You’ve already shown that there are $200$ possible choices for $n$. For each of these values of $n$ let

$$A_n=\{3^mn:m\ge 0\text{ and }3^mn<300\}\;;$$

the sets $A_n$ are a partition of $\{1,2,\ldots,299\}$ into $200$ parts. Now apply the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: I guess the problem implies that there must be two distinct powers of 3. So I guess 1 should be included in the set S3. Correct?

Comment: @user1745356: No: $1$ is not a **multiple** of $3$. In any case it isn’t actually the multiples of $3$ that are important: it’s the **non-multiples** of $3$ — or rather, the fact that there are only $200$ of them.

Comment: I meant that any integer is a multiple of zeroth power of 3 because 3^0=1. So among 201 integers there must at least 1 integer that is a multiple of 3^j where j > 0. And we can select any other integer even a prime because it is a multiple of 1 and 1 is a zeroth power of 3. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: @user1745356: I'm afraid not: the fact that $1$ is a power of $3$ is simply not relevant to the problem. You're not paying attention to the hint that I gave. You have $200$ sets $A_n$ and $201$ numbers, each of which is in one of the sets $A_n$; what does the pigeonhole principle tell you?

Comment: It turns out that I completely misunderstood the problem. I tried to find two numbers in the set that are MULTIPLES of 3. Thanks.

Comment: @user1745356: Ah, okay; that explains why it felt as if we were a bit at cross purposes! You're welcome.