# Show that in every set of 201 positive integers, each less than 301, there are two, the ratio of which is a power of 3

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

I tried to play around with the question and came up with some (possibly wrong) observations.

Firstly, I noticed that for there to be a ratio which is a power of 3, you must have $\frac{a}{b} = 3^n$. I counted all the powers of 3 lesser than 301.

These are $3,9,27,81,243$. Next, I realised that there are a 100 possible pairs with 3 as a common ratio, 33 possible pairs with 9 as a common ratio, 11 possible pairs with 27 as a common ratio, 3 possible pairs with 81 as a common ratio and 1 possible pair with 243 as a common ratio.

Eliminating the common pairs, I realised there must be $100 + 1 + 1 + 1 +1 + 1$ possible pairs in total. That is there are $105$ possible pairs.

Now I can use the pigeonhole principle to prove that at least one of the pairs must be filled. Is this proof wrong and if so where is it wrong?

Comment: Are the 201 integers distinct, or is 1 considered a power of 3?

Comment: the integers are distinct and 1 is not considered a power of 3. @preferred_anon

Comment: What do you mean by a common pair? If $a/b = 3$, then surely $a/b \ne 9$?

Comment: Divide any integer ("pigeon") from this set by $3$ until it cannot be divided anymore. The resulting numbers are not divisible by $3$ and *they* can be your "pigeonholes".

Comment: @StinkingBishop I am not sure what you mean

Comment: How many numbers between $1$ and $300$ are not divisible by $3$? Answer: $200$. How many numbers you have altogether? $201$. Thus (pigeonhole principle!), two of your numbers, when reduced by repeatedly dividing by $3$ will end up being the same. *Those* two numbers have a ration which is a power of $3$.

Comment: For a correct solution, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203505/show-that-for-any-set-of-201-positive-integers-less-than-300-there-must-be-two?rq=1).  If it weren't for the fact that you ask for solution-verification and asked specifically what is wrong with your attempt this would have been a duplicate.